# How to open a page with information about the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible via window.open to open a page with information about the version of the browser? My browser is Google Chrome.

```
window.open("chrome://version/");
```

This code opens a new tab "about:blank".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link to chrome:// url from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362775/link-to-chrome-url-from-a-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use any of the usual APIs from the Web platform to open `chrome://` pages.

These pages can be opened using [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) though:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'chrome://version'
});
```

Comment: I tried using this in content script but this is not working. It shows  `Cannot read property 'create' of undefined`

Comment: @ParagGangil This API is not available to content scripts. Put the `chrome.tabs.create` call in a [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), and [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from the content script to the background page to open the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to do this (security reason, probably):

Try typing that in the console:

```
window.location.href = "chrome://version/"
```

**output:** *Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://version/*