# How to open a chrome url (chrome://about) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I am currently working on a program that sends you to `chrome://about/` using the `window.open("chrome://about");` method. When I change the URL to something like [www.google.com](https://google.com) it works. Is this just my code or is it a problem with the `window.open()` command?

```html
<!doctype html>

<html >
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="aboutPage()">
    <h1>Open About</h1>
  </body>
  <script>
    function aboutPage(){
      window.open("chrome://about")
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is blocked for security reasons.

Comment: If you open the console you'll see the error: **js:23 Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://about/**

Comment: @Barmar are there any other methods to force it open?

Comment: If you're writing a Chrome extension you can use `chrome.tabs.create`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990129/how-to-open-a-page-with-information-about-the-browser/24990228#24990228

Comment: Yeah that answers it